# Numerical solution of exponential equation using Python or other software

Tags: python, scipy, exponential

I want to find numerical solutions to the following exponential equation where a,b,c,d are constants and I want to solve for r, which is not equal to 1.

a^r + b^r = c^r + d^r                        (Equation 1)

I define a function in order to use Scipy.optimize.fsolve:

```
    from scipy.optimize import fsolve
    def func(r,a,b,c,d):
        if r==1:
            return 10**5
        else:
            return ( a**(1-r)  +  b**(1-r) ) - ( c**(1-r)  + d**(1-r)  )


    fsolve(funcp,0.1, args=(5,5,4,7))
```

However, the fsolve always returns 1 as the solution, which is not what I want. Can someone help me with this issue? Or in general, tell me how to solve (Equation 1). I used an online numerical solver long time ago, but I cannot find it anymore. That's why I am trying to figure it out using Python.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply some mathematical reasoning when choosing the initial guess. Consider your problem f(r) = (5<sup>1-r</sup> + 5<sup>1-r</sup>) − (4<sup>1-r</sup> + 7<sup>1-r</sup>)

[image]

When r ≤ 1, f(r) is always negative and decreasing (since 7<sup>1-r</sup> is growing much faster than other terms). Therefore, all root-finding algorithms will be pushed to right towards 1 until reaching this local solution.

You need to pick a point far away from 1 on the right to find the nontrivial solution:

```
>>> scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda r: 5**(1-r)+5**(1-r)-4**(1-r)-7**(1-r), 2.0)
array([ 2.48866034])
```

Simply setting f(1) = 10<sup>5</sup> is not going to have any effect, as the root-finding algorithm won't check f(1) until the very last step<sup>(note)</sup>.

If you wish to apply a penalty, the penalty must be applied to a range of value around 1. One way to do so, without affecting the position of other roots, is to divide the whole function by (r − 1):

```
>>> scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda r: (5**(1-r)+5**(1-r)-4**(1-r)-7**(1-r)) / (r-1), 0.1)
array([ 2.48866034])
```

---

(note): they may climb like f(0.1) → f(0.4) → f(0.7) → f(0.86) → f(0.96) → f(0.997) → … and stop as soon as |f(x)| < 10<sup>-5</sup>, so your f(1) is never evaluated

Comment: Solid advice, +1. Alternatively, can use `brentq`, which explicitly requires the localization interval: `brentq(lambda r: 5**(1-r)+5**(1-r)-4**(1-r)-7**(1-r), 2, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

First of your code seems to uses a different equation than your question: `1-r` instead of just `r`.

Valid answers to the equation is `1` and `2.4886` approximately as can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E(1-x)%2B5%5E(1-x)-4%5E(1-x)-7%5E(1-x)%3D0). With the second argument of `fsolve` you specify a [starting estimate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html). I think due to `0.1` being close to `1` you get that result. Using the `2.1` as starting estimate I get the other answer `2.4886`.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(r,a,b,c,d):
    if r==1:
        return 10**5
    else:
        return ( a**(1-r)  +  b**(1-r) ) - ( c**(1-r)  + d**(1-r)  )

print(fsolve(func, 2.1, args=(5,5,4,7)))
```

Chosing a starting estimate is tricky as many give the following error: `ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.`